# Django 'Library' object has no attribute 'simple'

Tags: python, django

I am following the book "Django by Example", and right at the beginning of Chapter 3: Extending your blog application, I am trying to load my blog_tags file, however I get this AttributeError:

> In template /home/ahmad/Documents/Coding/Django By Example/Excercises/djangoblogapp/mysite/blog/templates/blog/post/list.html, error at line 1
>   'Library' object has no attribute 'simple'

Here is my base.html:

```
{% load blog_tags %}
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %} {% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/blog.css" %}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div id = "content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div id = "sidebar">
    <h2> My Blog</h2>
      <p> This is my blog. I've written {% total_posts %} posts so far. </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my post/list.html:

```
{% extends "blog/base.html" %}

{% block title %}My Blog {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1> My Blog </h1>

  {% if tag %}
    <h2>Posts tagged with "{{ tag.name }}"</h2>
  {% endif %}

  {% for post in posts %}
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.get_absolute_url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <p class="tags">
      Tags:
      {% for tag in post.tags.all %}
        <a href="{% url "blog:post_list_by_tag" tag.slug %}">
          {{ tag.name }}
        </a>
        {% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p class="date">
      Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}
    </p>

    {{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}
  {% endfor %}
  {% include "pagination.html" with page=posts %}
{% endblock %}
```

Lastly, here is my templatetags/blog_tags.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

from ..models import Post

@register.simple._tag(name='useless')
def total_posts():
    return Post.published.count()
```

I have exhausted Google and I cannot find any solution to my problem. I would greatly appreciate your help!

In case it helps, I am using Python 3.6.2 with virtualenvwrapper on a Linux system. Django version is 1.8.6

EDIT: New error that I am getting:

> In template /home/ahmad/Documents/Coding/Django By Example/Excercises/djangoblogapp/mysite/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 19
>   Invalid block tag: 'total_posts'

Basically, the error points towards this line of code:

```
<p> This is my blog. I've written {% total_posts %} posts so far. </p>
```

I don't see anything else that could be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to use [simple-tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags), remove dot

```
@register.simple_tag(name='useless')
#             ^^^^^
def total_posts():
```

and edit in the  *base.html*, 
replace

```
  written {% total_posts %} posts so far.
         <!-- ^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

to the name of simple tag

```
  written {% useless %} posts so far.
         <!-- ^^^^^^^^^ -->
```

Comment: That fixes my initial issue but now I am having another error:

In template /home/ahmad/Documents/Coding/Django By Example/Excercises/djangoblogapp/mysite/blog/templates/blog/base.html, error at line 19
Invalid block tag: 'total_posts'

I don't see anything else that could be an issue. Your help would be appreciated!

Comment: please add your new error with code format to question

Comment: i added new info to the answer